# How to store files in server in pure Node.js?

Tags: node.js, forms, file, upload, encode

I'm trying to write to disk a file uploaded POST inside a form with the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data", and i get the data in server and managed to sort it (get contents inside file and filename), but when i write in disk, the file is not readable. These images can illustrate my situatuion. Image1 shows how i'm getting data amd image2 shows how it is displayed. I don't know what's wrong.

I've trid encoding as base64, binary, and no encoding sending it straight as it comes from form, but no success.

[Image 1 http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=sou610&s=9#.XRuig-tKiUk](http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=sou610&s=9#.XRuig-tKiUk)
[Image 2 http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11jag49&s=9#.XRujROtKiUk](http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11jag49&s=9#.XRujROtKiUk)

The file gets stored in server, but it is not readable. I hope i could manage to get the file in server just as it is uploaded.

```js
if(request_param.method == "POST")
{
 var qs = require('querystring');
 var body = '';

 request_param.on('data', function(data)
 {
  body += data; //gets incoming data on buffer
 });

 request_param.on('end', function()
 {
  var util = require('util');
  var postvars_array = qs.parse(body);

  var boundary = body.substring(0, 40); //gets the boundary
  var line_separator = "\r\n";
  var array_post_fields = body.split(boundary);

  var array_post_field;
  var field_header_array;
  var file_content;
  var file_name;
  var file_name_arr;
  var file_ext;
  var file_ext_arr;

  for(f = 1; f < array_post_fields.length; f++) //parses the string from multipart form
  {
   array_post_field = array_post_fields[f].split(line_separator);
   field_header_array = array_post_field[1].split(";");
   if(field_header_array.length > 2)
   {
    file_name = field_header_array[2]; //gets filename
    file_name_arr = file_name.split("=");
    file_name = file_name_arr[1];
    file_name = file_name.replace('"', '');
    file_name = file_name.replace('"', '');
    file_content = array_post_field[4]; //gets file contents
   }
  }
  
  cont += '<br/><br/>';
  cont += '<br/><br/>';
  cont += file_name + '<br/><br/>' + file_content; //prints file contents, lots of diamonds (question signs)

  file_ext_arr = file_name.split(".");
  file_ext = file_ext_arr[file_ext_arr.length - 1];
  
  if(file_name != "")
  {
   const fs = require('fs');
   fs.writeFile("./shared/"+file_formats[file_ext]+"/"+file_name, file_content, function(err) //writes on disk (file gets saved but its unreadable)
   {
    if(err)
     return console.log(err);

    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile("./media/text/template.html", 'utf8', function(err, contents)
    {
     if(err)
      console.log(err);
     cont = contents.replace("<hydra-html-content>", cont);
     cont = cont.replace("<hydra-module-name>", "Archivos");
     cont = cont.replace("<hydra-title-page>", ".:Hydra / Archivos:.");

     response_param.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
     response_param.write(cont);
     response_param.end();
    });
   });
  }
  else
  {
   var fs = require('fs');
   fs.readFile("./media/text/template.html", 'utf8', function(err, contents)
   {
    if(err)
     console.log(err);
    cont = contents.replace("<hydra-html-content>", cont);
    cont = cont.replace("<hydra-module-name>", "Archivos");
    cont = cont.replace("<hydra-title-page>", ".:Hydra / Archivos:.");

    response_param.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    response_param.write(cont);
    response_param.end();
   });
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Please post code here. Not picture links.

Comment: I added the code i'm using, thanks.